# Error: install exited abnormally [1/1] while installing CentOS-5.4

Tags: centos, system-installation

In my system, I have installed ubuntu. I Follow this article : [How to Set Up a USB Key to Install CentOS](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey) to create bootable USB for CentOS-5.4.

Steps i have done after booting successfully:

1. Choose a language : English
2. Keyboard type: us
3. Installation Method: What type of media contains packages to be installed?

   Local CDROM, Hard drive, NFS image, FTP, HTTP. I choose **Hard drive** option
4. Select Partition : Press F2 & select partition where iso image exist.
   I am using iso : CentOS-5.4-x86_64-bin-1of7.iso. Select this iso image and press enter it shows:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why did this happen or how to troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i solved my problem:

Download another iso file : **CentOS-5.4-x86_64-bin-DVD_1.iso**, tried to create booable USB but couldn't work so write to DVD & installed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Hey below command I am using from  2 years. Do it as root user

`# dd if=/path/to/iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M ; sync`

And it worked everytime.

Note: At the time of installation if you are dropping to BusyBox shell then its a different issue.

If above command didnt worked for you then let me know what you did and what you got while trying.

Comment: I tried again with article i mentioned in question. boot successfully but still cannot install and i also tried  this command but cannot boot centos-5.4

Comment: @MicrosoftLinux , `boot successfully but still cannot install and i also tried this command but cannot boot centos-5.4` . I need more information. capture screenshot at where you stuck. there is a bug i know but with out seeing i cant help you much

Comment: I need at least10 reputation to add more screenshots. I think i need to modify a file from the article that i have preferred.  In that article,4th section it says:    Add to the "append" statements in the various sections:

  `method=hd:sda2:/centos`

To use kickstart:

  `ks=hd:sda2:/ks.cfg method=hd:sda2:/centos`  I didn't get this point. I think i did a mistake at here.

Comment: Can you try this https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=13577 and

Comment: ok.. i ll try but did you notice iso i have used. Do i have to use another 2of7, 3of7....& 7of7.iso files ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes , i had the same issue a few days back and the `dd` command didn't work for me , it couldn't find the media in the usb key. Then i downloaded Universal usb installer ,create bootable usb for CentOS and it worked. You can follow: [Create a bootable USB
stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Comment: I tried with Universal usb installer in windows but can't boot. Not worked for CentOS-5.4

Comment: Ok , then u can boot from usb and select the url option and provide the url to images